# Is a asp.net web application considered a process that runs inside a app pool?

Tags: asp.net, applicationdomain

Is a asp.net web application (hosted in IIS) considered a process?

And this process is in an application pool.

And there can be 1 or more application pools in a app domain?

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An *app pool* in IIS is a process (w3wp.exe), and an app pool can host several applications.

So, no, an ASP.NET application isn't considered a process, but it *can* be the only application hosted in an app pool.

*Note: I'm only considering IIS 6 and up.*